# Declaring an sf::SoundBuffer causes the program to crash at termination

Tags: c++, audio, sfml

I've been using SFML for a long time, but I've never used the Audio module before until now.

I wanted to add a sound effect to my game, so my first approach was similar to this...

```
class Deck : public sf::Drawable
{
public:
    ...

private:
    sf::Sound shuffleSound;

    ...

    static sf::SoundBuffer soundBuffer;
};
```

And the plan was to initialize `soundBuffer` once and do `shuffleSound.setBuffer(soundBuffer);` in the constructor of each object. But I got this error:

```
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed

Assertion failed: (lockret == althrd_success), function LockLists, file /Users/m/Desktop/tmp/openal/build_deps/openal-soft-openal-soft-1.17.2/Alc/ALc.c, line 776.
(lldb)
```

After googling this error, I saw an obscure message somewhere about not putting SFML resources at global scope. Figuring the `static` variable was the cause of the error, I tried this:

```
class Deck : public sf::Drawable
{
public:
    ...

private:
    sf::Sound shuffleSound;

    ...

    static std::unique_ptr<sf::SoundBuffer> bufptr;
};
```

And initialized the pointer once by calling `make_unique` if the object was empty, and then doing `shuffleSound.setBuffer(*bufptr)` in the constructor.

But, I still get the same error. The error doesn't happen until the program is about to terminate, BTW.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like SFML doesn't clean up correctly OpenAL resources when closing. Alc.h is a OpenAL util header, so this is a possible bug.

Comment: I can well imagine that there's a background thread servicing the render handler and you've just pulled the rug out from under it before stopping audio output

Answer (score 0):

I can't add any comment cause my reputation is too low so I will write the answer.

In the beginning, I would recommend you to create some class that would keep all your resources.
Check this: https://github.com/SFML/SFML-Game-Development-Book/tree/master/02_Resources/Include/Book

There are source codes of SFML Game Development book - you can find many helpful materials there, on SFML Github.

So, in your case you could create an object of that class of type: `ResourceHolder<sf::SoundBuffer, ID> mSoundHolder;` where ID is some `enum` type to identify each Sound.

Then to play your sound simply create object of type `sf::Sound s` and use `s.setBuffer(mSoundHolder.getResource(<YOUR_ID>)` and `s.play()`.

Make sure `sf::Sound` is not local object because it will not play as it will be destroyed quickly automatically. Then create it in class or if you want to play more sounds at the same create for example `std::list<sf::Sound> sounds` at iterare it to play sounds. To check it finished playing, use: `sound.getStatus() == sf::Sound::Stopped` comparison and then remove sounds from your list.

You can create `sf::Sound` object from `sf::SoundBuffer` what is helpful using `std::list`. Then simply you can use `emplace_back` on your list object and pass your `sf::SoundBuffer` as argument.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Neither the `Sound` or the `SoundBuffer` is local. Anyway, this doesn't really answer my question...